# Installing "en_US" in RHEL container

Tags: docker, redhat, redhat-containers

I'm testing an ansible role using [molecule](http://molecule.readthedocs.io/). The role install a corporate binary over which I've no insight, I'm just mean to `./binary --silent` and that's it. Over RedHat.

It work for a RedHat 6.9 VM. But it doesn't work over the docker container registry.access.redhat.com/rhel6:6.9.

The error message says:

> "Operating system bad language (en_US not found)".

What could be missing from the container that would be on the VM? Some localedef ...? I wasn't able to find a doc about this, but is there some RedHat description about the delta between their "minimal install from ISO" VMs and containers?

Thanks for any help

Comment: This is about a tools used for IaaC programming, I don't see the off topic here...

Answer (score 1):

If you run `locale -a` on the Docker image you're using, you'll get the following output:

```
C
en_US.utf8
POSIX
```

Run the same command in your VM and compare output. If it contains line `en_US` (without utf-8 suffix), try adding the following lines dicrectly below `FROM` directive in your `Dockerfile`:

```
RUN localedef -v -c -i en_US -f UTF-8 en_US; exit 0
RUN sed -i 's/en_US.UTF-8/en_US/g' /etc/sysconfig/i18n && source /etc/sysconfig/i18n
```

This will generate locale en_US with encoding UTF-8 named en_US (without any suffix).